# pandas, dataframe: If you need to process data row by row, how to do it faster than itertuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know that `.itertuples()` and `.iterrows()` are slow, but how can I speed them up if I need to use and process data one row at a time, as shown below?

```py
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

posts = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    post = Post(title=row.title, text=row.text, ...)
    posts.append(post)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension and unpacking (using `kwargs`) if your DataFrame columns have the same names as your class attributes. An example is shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"title": ["fizz", "buzz"], "text": ["aaaa", "bbbb"]})
posts = [Post(**kwargs) for kwargs in df.to_dict("records")]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is using apply function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(title=["title1", "title2", "title3"],text=["text1", "text2", "text3"]))

df["Posts"] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(title=x["title"], text=x["text"]), axis=1)

posts = list(df["Posts"])
print(posts)
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'title1', 'text': 'text1'}, {'title': 'title2', 'text': 'text2'}, {'title': 'title3', 'text': 'text3'}]
```

It's better to avoid a for loop when you have another methods to do that.

Comment: it is not better than using a loop, under the hood `apply` runs a loop over all the rows, so it is almost the same in fact, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2db3b0a0378487e269997700b14777af70838e95/pandas/core/apply.py#L829

Comment: You are right. Still I would use df.apply because I avoid writing for loops when possible.